# Transpose data in SQL ROws to column

Tags: sql, h2

I have one query

```
SELECT circlename, 
alarmname,
count(alarmname) as Count
from temip_alarm 
where alarmname='Site Down' or 
alarmname='Predicted_Site Down' or
alarmname='Mains Fail' or 
alarmname='Fire & Smoke' or 
alarmname='Shelter Temperature High' 
group by circlename, alarmname;
```

which gives me output like below:

```
CIRCLENAME        | ALARMNAME                | COUNT
Delhi             | Fire & Smoke             | 189
Mumbai            | Mains Fail               | 20
UP West           | Predicted_Site Down      | 380
Punjab            | Mains Fail               | 1
Kerala            | Site Down                | 55
Mumbai            | Shelter Temperature High | 3
Gujarat           | Mains Fail               | 189
Kerala            | Mains Fail               | 198
UP West           | Site Down                | 16
Punjab            | Shelter Temperature High | 1
Gujarat           | Shelter Temperature High | 21
Maharashtra & Goa | Site Down                | 1
Kerala            | Shelter Temperature High | 23
Gujarat           | Fire & Smoke             | 14
Kerala            | Fire & Smoke             | 7
Delhi             | Site Down                | 154
UP West           | Mains Fail               | 470
Haryana           | Mains Fail               | 19
Punjab            | Predicted_Site Down      | 5
Mumbai            | Fire & Smoke             | 1
UP West           | Shelter Temperature High | 92
Mumbai            | Site Down                | 9
UP West           | Fire & Smoke             | 79
Delhi             | Mains Fail               | 3663
Punjab            | Site Down                | 12
Gujarat           | Site Down                | 38
Delhi             | Shelter Temperature High | 266
Mumbai            | Predicted_Site Down      | 4
```

But I need data like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve this..

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: We are using H2 Db..

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT circlename, 
       sum(case when alarmname = 'Site Down' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteDownCount,
       ...,
       count(*) as GrandTotal
from temip_alarm 
where alarmname IN ('Site Down', 'Predicted_Site Down', 'Mains Fail',
                    'Fire & Smoke', 'Shelter Temperature High') 
group by circlename
```

Answer (score 0):

This has extended version by `@jarh` for SQL Server

```
SELECT (case when GROUPING(circlename) = 1 
             then 'GrandTotal' else circlename end) circlename, 
        sum(case when alarmname = 'Site Down' then 1 else 0 end) as SiteDownCount,
        ...,
        count(*) as GrandTotal
from temip_alarm 
where alarmname IN ('Site Down', 'Predicted_Site Down', 'Mains Fail',
                    'Fire & Smoke', 'Shelter Temperature High') 
group by rollup(circlename)
```

Comment: Hello @jarh Thanks for your reply.. I used this..but got following error   Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "GROUPING" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: @Vieypul.. `GROUPING` is available for `sql-server` as tagged. switch to `union all` or something similar.